# How to get the compaction strategy of C* cluster?

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

In the [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_configure_compaction_t.html) it says that the SizeTieredCompactionStrategy (STCS) is the default compaction strategy.

How can I get the actual compaction strategy of my cluster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compaction strategy is defined on **each table**

In **cqlsh**:

```
cqlsh:music> DESCRIBE TABLE artists;

CREATE TABLE music.artists (
    name text PRIMARY KEY,
    born text,
    country text,
    died text,
    gender text,
    styles list<text>,
    type text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    ...
    ...;
```